# Flex pattern for ID gives 'Segmentation fault'

Tags: c, regex

I have a program in C that converts expression to RPN (reverse Polish notation).
All I need to do is to replace lexer code written in C with Flex. I already did some work, but I have problems with patterns - word or variable id to be specific. Yes, this is class exercise.

This is what I have:

```
%{
    #include "global.h"
    int lineno = 1;
    int tokenval = NONE;
%}

%option noyywrap

WS             " "
NEW_LINE       "\n"
DIGIT          [0-9]
LETTER         [a-zA-Z] 
NUMBER         {DIGIT}+
ID             {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*

%%

{WS}+           {}
{NEW_LINE}      { ++lineno; }
{NUMBER}        { sscanf (yytext, "%d", &tokenval); return(NUM); }
{ID}            { sscanf (yytext, "%s", &tokenval); return(ID); }
.               { return *yytext;}
<<EOF>>         { return (DONE); }

%%
```

and defined in `global.h`

```
#define BSIZE 128
#define NONE -1
#define EOS '\0'
#define NUM 256
#define DIV 257
#define MOD 258
#define ID  259
#define DONE 260
```

All work when I use digits, brackets and operators, but when I type for example `a+b` it gives me `Segmentation fault` (and the output should be `ab+`). 
Please don't ask me for a parser code (I can share if really needed) - requirement is to ONLY implement lexer using Flex.

Comment: Don't know flex but I don't see an entry for `{LETTER }` where is it being used?

Comment: It is referenced in pattern for ID: `ID {LETTER}({LETTER}|{DIGIT})*`, then when pattern for ID is found, it runs the code (and it gives mentioned error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the program is doing an `sscanf` with a *string* format (`%s`) into the address of an integer (`&tokenval`).  You should change that to an array of `char`, e.g.,

```
%{
    #include "global.h"
    int lineno = 1;
    int tokenval = NONE;
    char tokenbuf[132];
%}
```

and

```
{ID}            { sscanf (yytext, "%s", tokenbuf); return(ID); }
```

(though `strcpy` is a better choice than `sscanf`, this is just a starting point).

Comment: Good point with type mismatch. Altough it still gives me the same error (Segmentation fault)

Comment: Ok. It came out I had to change some code inside parser after changes. But it works now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When flex scans a token matching pattern `ID`, the associated action attempts to copy the token into a character array at location `&tokenval`.  But `tokenval` has type `int`, so

1. the code has undefined behavior
2. if the length of the ID equals or exceeds the size of an `int`, then you cannot fit all its bytes (including a string terminator) in the space occupied by an `int`.  A reasonably likely result is that you attempt to write past its end, which could result in a segfault.

Comment: Good point. I added `char tokenbuf[255];` and changed `{ID} { sscanf (yytext, "%s", tokenbuf); return(ID); }`, but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Ok. It came out I had to change some code inside parser after changes. But it works now, thanks :)